# Choose which ViewController to switch to by using Picker View

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a restaurant app, in which the user could select which restaurant they would like to do on the first screen. After they've made their selection the user should press the begin button and it will take it to that View Controller

I have no idea how to get started, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Set label text in picker didselect delegate . then on button action method decide which vc to open on the basis of label text.

Answer (score 0):

Used button action is Done Button that we embed with picker to make final selection.

Use the following code: Works fine

```
import UIKit

class PickerViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerVieww: UIPickerView!
    var viewControllerArray = [String]()
    var value = Int()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pickerVieww.delegate = self
        pickerVieww.dataSource = self
        viewControllerArray = ["controller1","controller2","controller3"]
    }
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return viewControllerArray.count
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return viewControllerArray[row]
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView,didSelectRow row: Int,inComponent component: Int)
    {
        if(row == 0)  {
            value = 0
        }
        else if(row == 1) {
            value = 1
        }
        else{
            value = 2
       }
    }
    @IBAction func swicthToController(_ sender: Any) {

        if value == 0{
            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "first") as! asasasViewController
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        if value == 1{
            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "second") as! secondViewController
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        if value == 2{
            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "third") as! thirdViewController
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```